# I am running Jupyter notebook from the VS Code. Is there a way that I have the output in a separate space instead having them inline?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

Similar to the image below, but I want to do it for Jupyter notebook running in VS Code:
[image]

I could find solution that could potentially work had I been running the Jupyter notebook from the browser. But the same I couldnt find or work out for the running Jupyter notebook from VS Code.

The idea is have a similar arrangement as in MATLAB (running .mlx), where the code appears on the left and the output comes to the right.

Comment: I know you specified VScode but it may help others ending up here.... In the Jupyter ecosystem, you can use JupyterLab and toggle `View > Render Side-by-Side` to get this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, Visual Studio Code's Jupyter Notebook does not support displaying cell outputs to the right of the cell. The output is always displayed below the cell.

If you just want the code to be on the left, the output content is on the right, and running on both sides simultaneously, you can try the method below:

1. Right-click your current file and choose "Split Right". It'll open a same file on the right.

[image]

2. When you run the cell, the same file on the right will also run and display the output content at the same time. But this will not change the fact that the left cell will still display the output facts.

[image]